# Facebook Graph Api Read Conversations Between a Page and User

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using the fb graph api to get the conversations from a page. Here is the query:

**https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/page-id/conversations?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN**

However this query gets only the conversations which are in the **inbox** folder. I would like to know how can I query the conversations which are in the spam and archive folder.